# Check if element contains specific text - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image]

I need to check whether this string (group id element) contains anything but numbers, and if it does, do something else. I know jquery has :contains, but what does Selenium use? The CSS selector for this element is `#app > div.v-application--wrap > main > div > div > div.container > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div.row.no-gutters.align-start.justify-start.align-content-start > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.v-slide-group__wrapper > div > div:nth-child(4)`.

Comment: You want to check if a string contain numbers or something else ? You can use .isnumeric() or make a try catch converting it to a int for exemple

Comment: can I use .isnumeric() on a find_element_by_css_selector?

Comment: You need to use it directly on the text extracted unfortunatly

Comment: That's what I'm asking, how?

Comment: Use Beautifulsoup to get acess to the text, by using selector you're interacting with the webpage on the webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [isnumeric()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) on the div text.

```
if div.text.isnumeric():
    # Do something
```

Comment: how do I reach the text in the div tho? I got `groupId = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(groupIdCSS)`, but I can't do isnumeric on that. How do I actually access the text in it?

Comment: Simply use groupId.text

Comment: You need to use Beautifulsoup on the page_source

Comment: lol, makes sense. I think BS is killing it when .text exists.

Comment: @Tbaki I'm confused as to why beautifulsoup needs to be involved?

Comment: @Someprogammer Good question, basically, he was using the wrong access method i think. He was interacting with webdriver instead of the HTML source code